# client denied by server configuration (htaccess; order allow,deny)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

So I'm having the following "issue" where my log gets flooded with the following warnings:

```
[access_compat:error] AH01797: client denied by server configuration
```

This happens with every page someone tries to visit. Now I've already found that the issue is (probably) occuring because I'm still using `order allow,deny` in my `.htaccess`

```
...
Order allow,deny
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry AL good_country
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry AD good_country
Allow from env=good_country
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry US bad_country
Deny from env=bad_country
...
```

While the above htaccess works fine (people from good_country are let through, others are denied), the access_compat:error still shows up.

So removing `order allow,deny` causes the errors not to show up anymore, but it will also let everyone access the page.

Like I said before I've found that this error is possibly due to me using `order allow,deny` while the [Apache version is 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) (I can't be sure that version is 2.4 because I'm using shared webhosting but its the most likely explanation for now; phpinfo() doesn't show the Apache version).

Now I don't exactly know how to solve this, but I saw that you can use also use `require`, but I don't know how to use it in combination with `good_country` / `bad_country`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more searching and trial-and-error I found at that the following works fine for me and the "errors" stopped showing up

```
<RequireAll>
Require expr %{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} =~ /(AL|AD)/i
</RequireAll>
```

^ please note that there are no quotes around the expression (in contrary to the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html))